# system() in C is printing the passed command unlimited times rather than executing it - bug

Tags: c, cmd, system

I am not new to C programming, but what I faced today is new. The system() function is printing the passed command unlimited times rather than executing it. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char type[] = "exe";
    char name[] = "FileMaker";
    char jar_location[] = "D:\\Fida\\Codeblocks\\Java\\Projects\\FileHandling\\dist";
    char jar[] = "FileHandling.jar";
    char output_location[] = "D:\\Fida\\CodeBlocks\\java";
    char module_location[] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16.0.1\\jmods\"";
    char modules[] = "java.base";

    char mandatory_cmd[2048];

    sprintf(mandatory_cmd, "jpackage -t %s --name %s --input %s --dest %s --main-jar %s --module-path %s --add-modules %s", type, name, jar_location, output_location, jar, module_location, modules);
    puts(mandatory_cmd);
    system(mandatory_cmd);
}
```

A few pieces of info might help you:

1. The entered command is not prebuilt in windows. It has come from Java Development Kit 16.
2. I did edit my OS's environmental variable to add the path to my java.

One thing also to note that I once commented(//) the system() function to print the command with puts(); then I copied the printed command and pasted it in cmd myself, and it worked fine. Then why doesn't it work in the system() function?

Any help appreciated.

Regards,

Fida

Comment: What is the name of the executable file you're making?

Comment: At a minimum should do basic error checking - specifically check the `system` return value and call `perror` if it fails.

Comment: oh god! My PC almost hangs when I run this program. I used perror if the return value is -1 by the system() function. But it didn't return -1. Then, I tried removing the puts function, still no luck. And finally, I realized that my program is making HUNDREDs of instances of cmd, and the program itself, in my task manager. And it was taking more than 3GB of memory. It is extremely weird. Can you point out what is wrong?

Comment: I also tried using popen, but still not working. I don't wanna destroy my PC.

Comment: What happens if you run it in a cmd window? 
jpackage -t exe --name FileMaker --input D:\Fida\Codeblocks\Java\Projects\FileHandling\dist --dest D:\Fida\CodeBlocks\java --main-jar FileHandling.jar --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\jmods" --add-modules java.base

Comment: Please answer @joseph's question: What is the name of the executable file you're making? jpackage? if yes, you have to change it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, it works fine when I copy-paste the command in cmd. And I am using jpackage to package my java application with my custom JRE. Just to make this process a bit easy, I decided to make a C program to call the jpackage function, so that I don't have to use such a long and complicated command in cmd.

Comment: @Shams Ok, it is clear, but what is the name of your C program?

Comment: It is `Jpackage.c`. Do filenames even matter?

Comment: Yes, because you call your own program (Jpackage.exe) recursively (so it is an infinite loop). So 1) change its name, or 2) add full path to jpackage.

Comment: Aconcagua, I know C files can't be executed. I do am running the exe file after compilation.

Comment: Side note: you do not need to change the source file name, you can alternatively specify another output file name (would be `-o` for GCC, *possibly* for MSVC, too, but not sure on that – if using an IDE you might find appropriate settings somewhere).

Comment: Thanks, Laci. I'll try changing the filename. Now I understand why it works recursively. After I compile my c program, a Jpackage.exe is created in the same folder. And by calling the same Jpackage again, it runs the jpackage inside the same folder rather than the jpackage in my java home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'll insist on the easier way.

Comment: There's a third option (for completeness): According to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc723564(v=technet.10)#command-search-sequence]) changing the current working directory to anywhere else but the directory your executable resides in...